# Working with Intel TBB program using sniper simulator

Tags: simulation, tbb

I have setup sniper simulator from [Sniper](http://snipersim.org/w/Getting_Started) and am able to successfully execute fft test program using make and /bin/ls command using following->

> ./run-sniper -- /bin/ls

These commands execute successfully with sniper.

I have compiled Intel TBB's example program sub_string_finder_extended.cpp using

> gcc -O2 -DNDEBUG  -o sub_string_finder_extended.gcc sub_string_finder_extended.cpp -ltbb -lrt
>   ./sub_string_finder_extended.gcc

executes successfully without any error but when I run it with sniper using

> ./run-sniper -- ./sub_string_finder_extended.gcc

It hangs after displaying following output

> [SNIPER] Start [SNIPER]
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [SNIPER] Sniper using Pin frontend [SNIPER] Running full application
>   in DETAILED mode [SNIPER]
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [SNIPER] Enabling performance models [SNIPER] Setting instrumentation mode to DETAILED
>   Done building string.

I googled about it but am unable to find any topic related to working of Intel TBB on sniper, however on sniper's wiki page it is mentioned that intel TBB programs are supported.

EDIT:
Sniper v-6.1
OS- ubuntu 12.04 LTS

uname -r output->
3.5.0-23-generic

Intel TBB (compiled from ) -> https://github.com/01org/tbb

Comment: Could you please provide some additional information: OS, TBB version

Comment: @ntfs.hard Added information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, TBB is still working properly in [Sniper](http://snipersim.org).

I think the problem you might be having is that detailed simulation can take quite some time, and therefore it might appear as though Sniper is hanging. A quick check with [Pin](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool)'s mix-mt tool shows that the application executes 53B instructions in total, which will take more than a day in detailed simulation. One way to check to see what is going on in Sniper would be to add the `-sprogresstrace` option to enable the `${SNIPER_ROOT}/scripts/progresstrace.py` script.

These examples were run on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (3.13.0-32-generic), using TBB with a gitid of `eb6336ab`, Sniper 6.1 and Pinplay-2.2-pin-2.14-71313.

### A Brief Example

#### Command line options explained

1. Run with 2 cores (`-n2`)
2. Start simulation after 30B instructions of fast forward
3. End after simulating 30M instructions
4. Use the faster, cache-only Nehalem-Lite core model (`-cnehalem-lite`) for this example (not typically used for detailed simulation)
5. Report progress (progresstrace.py modified to show progress every 10B instructions, `-sprogresstrace`)

#### Output

```
$ ${SNIPER_ROOT}/run-sniper -n2 -sstop-by-icount:30000000:30000000000 --roi-script -cnehalem-lite -sprogresstrace -- ${TBB_ROOT}/examples/GettingStarted/sub_string_finder/sub_string_finder_extended

 Done building string.
[STOPBYICOUNT] Starting after 30000000000 instructions
[STOPBYICOUNT] Then stopping after simulating 30000000 instructions in detail
 Done with serial version.
[STOPBYICOUNT] Starting ROI after 30000000005 instructions
[STOPBYICOUNT] Ending ROI after 30000002 instructions (30000000 requested)
[SNIPER] End
[SNIPER] Elapsed time: 316.56 seconds

$ head -n5 sim.out 
                                   | Core 0     | Core 1    
  Instructions                     |   14996162 |   15002407
  Cycles                           |   16365757 |   16365757
  IPC                              |       0.92 |       0.92
  Time (ns)                        |    6152540 |    6152540
```

### Detailed Output

```
$ ${SNIPER_ROOT}/run-sniper -n2 --no-cache-warming -sstop-by-icount:30000000:30000000000 --roi-script -cnehalem-lite -sprogresstrace -- ${TBB_ROOT}/examples/GettingStarted/sub_string_finder/sub_string_finder_extended
[SNIPER] Start
[STOPBYICOUNT] Starting after 30000000000 instructions
[STOPBYICOUNT] Then stopping after simulating 30000000 instructions in detail
[SNIPER] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[SNIPER] Sniper using Pin frontend
[SNIPER] Running in script-driven instrumenation mode (--roi-script)
[SNIPER] Using FAST_FORWARD mode for warmup
[SNIPER] Using CACHE_ONLY mode for detailed
[SNIPER] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Done building string.
[PROGRESS] 10000M instructions, 94977 KIPS, 1.00 IPC
[PROGRESS] 20000M instructions, 95086 KIPS, 1.00 IPC
 Done with serial version.
[STOPBYICOUNT] Starting ROI after 30000000005 instructions
[SNIPER] Enabling performance models
[SNIPER] Setting instrumentation mode to CACHE_ONLY
[PROGRESS] 30000M instructions, 99674 KIPS, 2.00 IPC
[STOPBYICOUNT] Ending ROI after 30000002 instructions (30000000 requested)
[SNIPER] Disabling performance models
[SNIPER] Leaving ROI after 0.58 seconds
[SNIPER] Simulated 30.0M instructions, 28843.6M cycles, 0.00 IPC
[SNIPER] Simulation speed 52057.4 KIPS (26028.7 KIPS / target core - 38.4ns/instr)
[SNIPER] Sampling: executed 0.00% of simulated time in detailed mode
[SNIPER] Setting instrumentation mode to FAST_FORWARD
[SNIPER] End
[SNIPER] Elapsed time: 316.56 seconds
```